# Image upload dimension validation

Tags: media

How can I add image dimension validation so that it accept only specific dimension of image?

For example I want to restrict to upload only 1200x650 dimension of image, so I have added same dimension in max and min upload dimension under image field settings. If I am uploading below 1200x650 it show validation error but not showing if image dimension is greater that 1200x650.

Comment: You can always use image styles to resize and crop the images. As a user, it would be annoying having to upload an image of exact size.

Comment: Image styles degrade image quality so we have decided to display actual image.

Comment: @RajeshVishwakarma, If you're just concerned about quality reduction in Image Style. You can configure image style to use 100% quality of image, by navigating to **"Admin => Configure => Media => Image Toolkit"**.